# What is the fastest 128-bit non-cryptographic hash function?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, performance, optimization

I need a **128-bit hash function** which is **extremely fast** since it will be used for generating unique IDs for billions of objects. It doesn't need to be a cryptographic hash function nor does it have to act as a PRF (though I would imagine any decent one would).

The only requirements are **amazing collision resistance and speed** (along with 128-bit output).

IDs are generated in two ways. Either by hashing another (128-bit) ID or by hashing 2 IDs (which would be concatenated together). This means the hash function would **only have to be fast for 128 and 256-bit inputs**.
The IDs for the initial objects which are not derived from other objects are just generated randomly (perhaps by hashing numbers 0 to N, where N is at most in the order of hundreds).

I came across XXH128, but I wonder if anyone knows if there are any potentially better alternatives for my usecase.

Comment: If you only need to hash 128/256-bit values, and you think these values are already "generated randomly" then hash 128-bit values by doing nothing and hash 256-bit values by throwing away half the data (or xor'ing the two halves). If inputs are truly random then you'll avoid collisions up to $\sim 2^{64}$ inputs which is the best you could hope for from a 128-bit hash.

Comment: @Mikero Yes, but which hash function should I use? Also, I don't think I can XOR the two 128-bit IDs because I would get the same output if IDs switch places. For that scenario, I need to get a different ID (If I had 2 objects with IDs 123 and 456 and another 2 with IDs 456 and 123 - they would have to produce different distinct new objects and XORing them would produce the same ID for both cases).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I understand the problem better.

Comment: [SipHash](https://github.com/veorq/SipHash) with a nul key?

Comment: Or $\text{Hash}(A, B) = \text{ROL}(A, 1) + B$; that avoids the issue of $\text{Hash}(A, B) = \text{Hash}(B, A)$ (which is only a problem if $(A, B)$ is a probable identifier when $(B, A)$ is an identifier).